# How to get text of XML tag using XPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have here a simple xml tag and I just wanted to get the text of the attribute that has `"en"`
on it and I wanted to get it base on the attribute value so I am doing it by XPATH

```
<tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>Samp</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Python is cool!</seg></tuv>
</tu>
```

as you can see there the attribute for `<tuv>` tag is `xml:lang`  then I tried this code right here

```
print(body_xml.find("tu").find('./tuv[@xml:lang="en"]').find("seg").text)
```

However it gives me this error

```
 raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix) from None
SyntaxError: prefix 'xml' not found in prefix map
```

The thing also is I tried to remove the `xml:` and so the `"lang"` is left then I tried to put it this way `print(body_xml.find("tu").find('./tuv[@lang="en"]').find("seg").text)` and IT WORKED!
Now I am just wondering I think the problem is it's because of this character `:`  so could there be a way to like formally do this correctly? I am very much open for any suggestions here in this great community :) Thank you for helping me fellow programmers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) when you call `find`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>Samp</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Python is cool!</seg></tuv>
</tu>'''

nsmap = {"xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
seg_txt = root.find('.//tuv[@xml:lang="en"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text
print(seg_txt)
```

output

```
Python is cool!
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! You are awesome! I love people like you! May I ask @balderman if why did you put that website? as the value of the key "xml" and put it on the second argument on the .find() function... I am just curious I mean I visited the site and read about it... did you put it there to let the script know about the namespace?

Also may I ask what this part of code does? root = ET.fromstring(xml) 
Did you convert the xml string into an xml tree so that you can parse it? Thank you!